# Hyper-V W10 (Host) Ubuntu 18.04 (Guest): Why does enhanced session mode not work?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a guest system on a Windows 10 host system using Hyper-V and I want to use the guest system in full-screen mode. To resize the screen as far as I have learned I need to run the guest system in enhanced session mode.

If I am connecting to the guest system it neither lets me choose the screen size nor activate the Enhanced Session Mode.

Enhanced Session Mode (User) and Enhanced Session Mode Policy (Server) are activated under the Hyper-V Settings.

I have also tried to deactivate the RemoteFX setting -> no changes

Guest services are activated -> no changes

As far as I have learned Ubuntu 18.04 LTS should already support the enhanced session mode.

Comment: do you have windows 10 with the update 1803 installed? is the vm a generation 2 vm? did you make sure to use the latest configuration version?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I will try to update to 1803 as soon as MS has fixed the Chrome issue. Generation 2 VM is configured. What do you mean with using the latest configuration version?

Comment: After some further research, the W10 1803 update might indeed be the solution to the window scaling problem: [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/01/27/introducing-vmconnect-dynamic-resize/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Guenther Schmitz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50192136/7926064) stated, this feature is part of Windows 10 Update 1803, in order to try it, you need at least build 17063 (as stated [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2018/02/28/sneak-peek-taking-a-spin-with-enhanced-linux-vms/)).

If you "only" want to increase your guest screensize, you might want to try [setting the videomode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50142872/7926064). Careful that you remove any `RemoteFX 3D Hardware`. This way you can achieve `1920x1080`.

Answer (score 7):

It fails when the auto login is enabled on Ubuntu. I disabled the auto login and it worked. Also make sure you enter your user name lowercase even if it has caps.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the xrdp login screen no matter what - can't log in.

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me as well. I was so confused, it took over 10Hrs to download the `Quick Create` image, and I waited so that it would be configured for me correctly 100% and... didn't work immediately!

Comment: Works form me. For future readers: To disable login, go to Settings, Users section, click Unlock on the top right of the window, enter password to unlock and turn off the Auto-login toggle button.

Comment: Strangely enough this fixed also a problem I had with the terminal not starting

Answer (score 0):

This functionality comes with Windows 10 Update 1803

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday with 19.04, tried all of the workarounds I could find in the internet and nothing helped. if I used 800x600 resolution everything worked "perfectly", when I tried full screen, it would kick me out... then I installed 18.04 LTS and everything just worked....

Answer (score -2):

I have found this guide, which helped me to activate the Enhanced Session Mode: https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/107147-guide-how-run-ubuntu-18-04-enhanced-mode-hyper-v.html

However, I am not able to connect to the VM using xorg because it always gives me the error "Video remoting was disconnected" and only the options to Reconnect or Exit.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: The script downloads the entire internet on your server, or close, as a side effect of dependencies. At least it installed LibreOffice and Thunderbird?